Maximal value of $\sum_{n=1}^N z^T X(P_n X + I)^{-1}z$ over positive semidefinite cone?
Let $z$ denote a unit vector.
Fix a finite collection of positive semidefinite matrices $\mathcal{P}$.
Define the function and set
$$
f_{\mathcal{P}}(X) = \sum_{P \in \mathcal{P}} z^T X(PX + I)^{-1} z, 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\mathcal{X} = \{X \succeq 0,~\mathrm{trace}(X) = 1\}. 
$$
Above, $X \succeq 0$ means that $X$ is a real, symmetric, and positive semidefinite matrix.
I am interested in the following quantities,
$$
f^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \sup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f_{\mathcal{P}}(X) 
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
X^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \mathrm{argmax}_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f_{\mathcal{P}}(X).
$$
By continuity and compactness, the supremum is attained and both quantities are well-defined.
In the case $|\mathcal{P}| = 1$, I am able to directly compute this. I obtain
$$
f^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = z^T(I + P)^{-1} z \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
X^\star_{\mathcal{P}} = \frac{(I+P)^{-1} zz^T (I + P)^{-1}}{z^T (I+P)^{-2} z}.
$$
Above, $\mathcal{P} = \{P\}$.
However, my proof does not generalize to $|\mathcal{P}| > 1$. I am wondering if there is a more clever way to obtain this result. Even an understanding in the case $|\mathcal{P}| > 2$ would be useful.

Proof for $|\mathcal{P}| = 1$:  Write $\mathcal{P} = \{P\}$. We claim
$$
f_\mathcal{P}(X) = z^T X(PX + I)^{-1} z \leq z^T(P + I)^{-1} z. 
$$
This follows from
$$
X(PX + I)^{-1} = \lim_{\tau \to 0^+} (P + (X + \tau I)^{-1})^{-1} \preceq (P + I)^{-1},
$$
since $X \preceq I$ as $X \in \mathcal{X}$. On the other hand, if $X_w = ww^T$ for unit norm $w$,
$$
f_\mathcal{P}(X_w)= \frac{(w^T z)^2}{w^T(I + P) w} = z^T(I+P)^{-1}z,
$$
if we set $w = w_\star = \tfrac{(I + P)^{-1} z}{\|(I +P)^{-1} z\|}$.
Note $X_{w_\star} = X^\star_\mathcal{P}$, as needed.

What is your proof for the $|\mathcal{P}|=1$ case?

Thanks. I appreciate that the questions I am asking seem trivial (and probably are) but: (i) why $X \preceq I$ implies that $\lim_{\tau \to 0^+} (P + (X + \tau I)^{-1})^{-1} \preceq (P + I)^{-1}$, (ii) why $X_w = ww^T$ implies that $z^T X(PX + I)^{-1} z=\frac{w^T z}{w^T(I + P) w}$? If you don't have the time to answer a reference will do.

Yes once you plug in $w_\star$ you get $z^T(I+P)^{-1}z$. My question was: given $f(P)=z^TX(PX+I)^{-1}z$ when $X_w=ww^T$ how do you  get $f(X_w)=\frac{w^Tz}{w^T(I+P)w}$.

By the way $(P+(X+\tau I)^{-1})^{-1} \succeq \left( X + \frac{1}{1+\tau}I\right)^{-1}$ does not yield the claim when $\tau \rightarrow 0^+$.

@TedBlack, there was a typo previously (missing a square). Also, yes I should have said $(P + (X + \tau I)^{-1})^{-1} \succeq ({\color{red}{P}} + \tfrac{1}{1+\tau} I)^{-1}$. Does this clarify?

OK thanks. It would be great if you could clarify or give a reference why $f_\mathcal{P}(X_w)= \frac{(w^T z)^2}{w^T(I + P) w}$. If I plug in $ww^T$ I get $z^T w w^T (Pww^T+I)^{-1}z$; then I can take out $z^Tw$ and I am left with $w^T(Pww^T+I)^{-1}z$. How do you go from this to $\frac{w^Tz}{w^T(I+P)w}$?

Use the Sherman Morrison formula.

I thought it is only applicable if $P$ is non-singular. You assume $P \succeq 0$.

? The Sherman Morrison Formula implies that $(I + uv^T)^{-1} = I - \tfrac{1}{1+u^T v} uv^T$. Apply this with $u = Pw, v = w$?

Thanks. Can you recommend a reference on the subject of matrix inequalities?

Since a function like $\frac{x}{1+px}$ is monotonic for $x\in (0,1)$ isn’t it the case that even for $\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}} z^T X(PX+I)^{-1}z$ the supremum is $\sum_{P\in \mathcal{P}} z^T (P+I)^{-1}z$?

How will you achieve this? The scalar case is misleading (the optimum is attained for all $p$ at $x= 1$). However, the choice $X = I$ is not feasible (its trace is too large when the dimension is large than $1$).

I was not recommending $X=I$! But the function is monotonic so I was thinking that the solution for $|{\cal P}|>1$ should be similar to that for the scalar case.

But why should it be? You provide a valid upper bound, but it is not attainable.
